Saw-toothed forward rate yield curve structure
I am trying to derive money market yield curve from observable IRS swap rates. IRS float coupon pays average 7D forward rate each quarter in arrears. For the last 2 years i've been using bootstrapping with an assumption of linear interpolation between average forward rates (which i think is a reasonable one) and doing a term shift to get regular (non-average) forward rates (because with an aforementioned linearity assumption average forward rate in coupon period equals forward rate in the middle of that period). Most of the time I was getting a pretty smooth curve considering the fact that market is illiquid and i have at most 14 observable swap rates.
However, for the last month or so I've been getting saw-spiked forward rate curves like the one below.

So i tried to smooth it with Nelson-Ziegel function but it didn't net me any good results, since i applied it to spot curve which was already smooth. So i decided to change the object of bootstrap. First i started bootstrapping with an assumption of linearity between 7D non-average rates (using which i calculated coupons). Next i tried using spot linearity.
All 3 methods give relatively similiar results in terms of spot curves (like 4-5 bps difference). But when i start comparing 7D forward curves i get (expectedly) very different results and all of them show spikey structure.

So i would like to ask for any pointers of what should i do next (to get a more smooth forward curve).
Should i maybe use different type of interpolation or maybe some parametrisation (if so, is it reasonable to apply it to a forward curve).
My intuition tells me that manipulating spot curve is the more rational way to do it, but I can't think of a way to get rid of these yearly spikes
P.S. I dont use same curve for discounting - i derive DFs from which uses daily compounding (like SOFR, ESTER etc.):
https://iss.moex.com/iss/analyticalproducts/curves/securities/RUB_OIS.json?from=2024-9-30&till=2024-9-30
7d AVG swap data:https://iss.moex.com/iss/analyticalproducts/curves/securities/RUB_KEYRATE_IRS.json?from=2024-9-30&till=2024-9-30

Can you actually provide the raw data you are working with? Difficult for anyone to reverse engineer what you are doing withoyt it.

Sure, i am using data from MOEX Api: https://iss.moex.com/iss/analyticalproducts/curves/securities/RUB_KEYRATE_IRS.json?from=2024-9-30&till=2024-9-30
